# AWS ECS Memory Definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Is Memory for hard and soft limits for tasks in terms of RAM or is it in terms of storage memory?
Mainly, does a docker volume that I attach to a container take up this memory?

Comment: It's RAM. I am not sure I have ever seen a technical document call disk storage "memory".

Answer (score 1):

No. Attached volumes are a straight read from the host disk, nothing to do with provisioned memory. `tmpfs` mounts are an exception, as they write to memory: https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/